# Need help in solving integral

Tags: integration

$$\int\frac{dx}{(z^{2}+x^{2})^{3/2}}$$
I arrived at this after a substitution $t=x/z$:
$$\frac{1}{z^{2}}\int\frac{dt}{(1+t^{2})^{3/2}}$$
but now stuck with that 3/2 in the exponent.

Comment: Try the standard substitution $x=z \tan(t)$.

Comment: Try a trigonometric substitution: construct a right triangle with catheti $z$ and $x$, and see what happens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us substitute $x = z \tan(t)$. Differentiating we get
$ dx = \frac{z\, dt}{\cos^2(t)}$. Now,
$$ \int \frac{z\,dt}{\cos^2(t) z^3 (1+\tan^2(t))^{3/2}}=$$
$$ \frac{1}{z^2} \int \frac{dt}{\cos^2(t) (\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)})^{3/2}}=$$
$$ \frac{1}{z^2} \int \cos(t) \,dt=  \frac{1}{z^2} \sin(t) + C = $$
$$ \frac{1}{z^2} \frac{x}{\sqrt{z^2+x^2}} + C,$$
where the back-substitution is done (as in the above remark by Matemáticos Chibchas) by constructing a right triangle.

Comment: Hi Teddy, in 2nd passage shouldn't it be $\int|\cos t|dt$ ?

Comment: Formally you're right. However, $x$ runs over all real values as $t\in (-\pi/2, \pi /2)$, and in this last interval, $\cos(t)>0$.

Comment: Oh, I've missed it. Then it is perfectly fair to omit the |.|.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try a hyperbolic substitution:

$$\frac{x}{z}=\sinh u\Longrightarrow dx=z\cosh u$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{(z^2+x^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{z^3}\int z\cosh u\; du\frac{1}{(1+\sinh^2u)^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{z^2}\int\frac{du}{\cosh^2 u}=$$

$$=\frac{2}{z^2}\int\frac{e^udu}{e^{2u}+1}=\frac{2}{z^2}\arctan e^u+C\ldots$$